# How to package .java files in VS code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

I used to work on 'IntelliJ Idea community' where I used to create new projects and files and it automatically packaged each newly created file. Now I started to code on 'VS Code' where I have to do all the stuff manually.
Recently I created a folder named "VS_Code" and created a dozen of .java files in it. I tried to use `package VS_Code;` in each file to put them in a single package but it suggests,

> The declared package "VS_Code" does not match the expected package ""

I might not know how to use 'package'. Please help me.

Comment: hi & welcome! :-) "Package" means the folder(structure) relatively to a "source root".

Comment: In your case it seems, you declared `package VS_Code;`, but the (source) files are located in the "source root" (so `VS_Code`, that's why "he" proposes package ""(<root)).. 2. upper case letters(+many others) are not allowed in "package".

Comment: solution: create a folder: `VS_Code/mypackage`, move all java files there, replace (in all files) `package VS_Code` with `package mypackage`.